# How to pass data from form FormSeetController to the ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, objective-c-blocks

i trying to use this package:

https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController

now my question, i trying to pass data between the FormSeetController to the ViewController after i dismiss the formSheet.

here what i tried so far:
in the ViewController in the button which creat the form:

```
formSheet.didDismissCompletionHandler = ^(UIViewController *vc){
// maybe i can use UIViewController *vc as my SearchGardenView (form Sheet), but how?

    [self formSheetDidDismissed]; // here i tryin to get the kidGardenID but its always nil;
};
```

and this is in the from the FormSeetController:

```
    AddKid *kid = [[AddKid alloc]init];
    NSArray *temp = [_responseDict valueForKey:@"ID"];
    kid.kidGardenID = [temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self mz_dismissFormSheetControllerAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {

      //this block dismiss the formSheet.
}];
```

im need to pass the 'kidGardenID' to ViewController but its always nil even after i gave it a value as the code above show..
maybe because the ViewController is already load and when i came back from the fortSheet its not load again?

i need to find a way to pass that data,
may you help me please?

**EDIT**
i tried use delegate with out success, the delegate is not called.
here is my delegate code:

setting the delegate (ViewControllerB)

```
@class SearchGardenTable;
@protocol SearchGardenDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(SearchGardenTable *)controller didFinishWithGardenID:(NSString *)gardenID gardenName:(NSString*)gardenName andCityName:(NSString*)cityName;
@end

@interface SearchGardenTable : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SearchGardenDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

telling VC B that VC A is its delegate:

```
 self.searchGarden.delegate = self; // in VC A viewDidLoad.
```

setting the parameters i want to pass back from VC B to VC A:

```
    _kidGaedenID  = [temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _kidGardenName = [temp1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishWithGardenID:_kidGaedenID gardenName:_kidGardenName andCityName:_kidCityName];
```

implement the protocol method at VC A:

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(SearchGardenTable *)controller didFinishWithGardenID:(NSString *)gardenID gardenName:(NSString*)gardenName andCityName:(NSString*)cityName
{
    _kidGardenID = gardenID;
    _gardenName.text = gardenName;
    _kidCity.text = cityName;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try willDismissCompletionHandler instead. This is defined in MZFormSheetController.h file.Type case the parameter presentedViewController to your view controller (AddKid I assume) and you can access properties of AddKit class here.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) MZFormSheetCompletionHandler willDismissCompletionHandler;

formsheet.willDismissCompletionHandler = ^(UIViewController *presentedViewController){
((AddKid*)presentedViewController).kidGardenID // should be accessible now.
```

};

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MZNavigationView kidGaedenID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10e1907f0'

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass details back to your parent view controller you should set up a delegate protocol which will allow exactly what you're looking for.

If you've not created any delegate protocols before, then once you have read this tutorial and used it a couple of times, you will find you use it a lot.

There are many good tutorial about this, though here is a good place to start

[Create your own Objective-C Delegate Protocol](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tip-create-your-own-objective-c-delegate-protocol/)

Hope this helps